# Pine Scripts TF alert incompatible problem

Tags: pine-script

I made a short code at PineScripts, want to send an alert, but encounter an error message as below. Can anyone help? Thank you.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test", overlay = true, timeframe="60")
fcross() => (close > open)
barcolor(fcross() ? color.white : na)
if fcross() 
    alert("Crossing 50SMA in Best TimeRange", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In this case the error message should be transcribed as text.

Answer (score 0):

the timeframe="60" argument is not compatible with functions that have side effect , so you have to use it in another way. Using request.security() function inside the code will give the same result.

request.security() function helps in getting higher timeframe data,
below code calls the "60 minute" timeframe data on any timeframe , you can change the input as per your requirements.

```
HTF=request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"60",fcross())
```

Here is the example code where I have used the security function to replicate what you wanted to achieve.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test", overlay = true)
fcross() => (close > open)

HTF=request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"60",fcross())
barcolor(HTF ? color.white : na)
if HTF
    alert("Crossing 50SMA in Best TimeRange", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Comment: I have some other codes about SMA, and I want it to work at 60m fixed, that's why I put timeframe="60" in the indicator. Is it possible to keep it?    
Thanks